# Create file in project directory with archetype plugin

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I want to place a `README.md`(and maybe some other files) next to the `pom.xml` of the project that is created by the Maven Archetype plugin.

[It seems](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html) that it is only allowed to place files

- `<sources> = src/main/java`
- `<resources> = src/main/resources`
- `<testSources> = src/test/java`
- `<testResources> = src/test/resources`
- `<siteResources> = src/site`

whereas I want to place files in `.`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To clarify what user1811587 is saying, if you are using an [archetype-metadata.xml](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-common/archetype-descriptor.html) file, like the one created when generating an archetype through [mvn archetype:create-from-project](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/advanced-usage.html), the format would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archetype-descriptor xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-descriptor-1.0.0.xsd" name="viewport-bootstrap"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="false" encoding="UTF-8">
      <directory/>
      <includes>
        <include>README.txt</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</archetype-descriptor>
```

The above XML  will place the README.txt along side the pom.xml.

Comment: +1, oddly enough `<directory>.</directory>` won't work -- it needs to be empty.

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
<resources>
        <resource>README.txt</resource>
</resources>
```

should help you.

Comment: if you are using archetype-metadata.xml, you need to define a fileSet <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="false"><directory />
   <includes>
    <include>readme.txt</include>
   </includes></fileSet>

Comment: Can you clarify the use of `resources`? I assume you mean the `resources` tag in the archteype descriptor `archetype.xml` in `src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/`? Wouldn't resources named there be put in `src/main/resources`?

Comment: Even I am not sure of this because that is what the documentation looks like,but if the mentioned configuration snippet does work.Sorry could not help on this.